# Merging duplicate records in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp

Using Cake 2.3.8.

I have a table that stores standard Customer information (name, email address, phone, etc). I have several other tables that store information related to the Customer (passport, address, communication logs, etc). These tables have a `customer_id` FK field in them.

When a person fills out the contact form, a new Customer record is automatically created. Depending on what information was requested, there may have been other associated records created with them.

It is possible that the Customer already exists in the database, so human eyes need to look and see if the new Customer is a match for an existing Customer. If there is a match, the application replaces the existing contact information with the new and deletes the new Customer record.

I want to know if there is an easy way to update any of the associated records as well. I can go through each association and manually update the foreign key to point to the existing Customer record, but it seems like there might be a better way to do it within the framework that I'm missing.

Is updating each association's foreign key the best/right way to do this?

Comment: You update the associated models' customer_id field manually, before deleting the new customer record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was the only way that I saw to do it, but I thought it was worth it to ask if there was a better way.